# Browse old revisions of a git Repository

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit, gitk

In SVN/TortoiseSVN, there was the GUI 'Repository Browser', which allowed to browse a previous 'state' of a repository. For example, I could go to log, pick an old revision, right-click on it, choose 'Browse repository', and then I had an Explorer-like GUI showing me the state of the repository at this time. This was particularly useful when I just wanted to see the state of the repository on a certain **date**, even if some of the files have not been changed then.

I have not found a similar feature in git. Both TortoiseGit and gitk allow me to view the log, but when I pick a revision, I cannot browse the **whole** repository state.

I certainly could check-out the old revision and browse it on the local drive, or revert my working copy to the old revision, but I found the TortoiseSVN feature much more user-friendly, since it allowed to quickly look up the state of file X or folder Y on day Z, without having to change local files and remembering to change them back later.

Can you do something similar in any Windows git GUI?

Thank you!

Comment: Because repository is local, checkout costs nothing. `git checkout [commit-ref]` GUI-equivalent

Comment: In command line, `git show <treeish>:/path/to/file` will show state of the file in particular commit.

Comment: May be also [git-mount](https://github.com/duairc/git-mount) can create views to commits in filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do this with `gitk` by using:

`gitk --all`

This will show all branches in your gitk interface.  Then select the `Tree` radio button.  Instead of showing you the diff in each commit, it will show you the repository tree now.  You should be able to browse the contents of the repository for each commit.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I'm looking for, but when I switch to the Tree radio button, the area below stays empty, no matter what commit I choose.

Comment: Now it works, I have no clue why it did not work 30 minutes ago. Thank you!